# Paypal Callback url for android

Tags: android, paypal

Am calling PayPal Here APpp from my application using the following url

```
"paypalhere://takePayment/?returnUrl={{returnUrl}}&invoice=%7B%22merchantEmail%22%3A%22%22,%22payerEmail%22%3A%22spotireddy-biz%40paypal.com%22,%22itemList%22%3A%7B%22item%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22{{name}}%22,%22description%22%3A%22{{description}}%22,%22quantity%22%3A%221.0%22,%22unitPrice%22%3A%22{{price}}%22,%22taxName%22%3A%22Tax%22,%22taxRate%22%3A%220.0%22%7D%5D%7D,%22currencyCode%22%3A%22{{currency}}%22,%22paymentTerms%22%3A%22DueOnReceipt%22,%22discountPercent%22%3A%220.0%22%7D";
```

Any idea how to replace the merchantEmail and payerEmail from this url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed.. :)

here s the code

```
"paypalhere://takePayment/?returnUrl={{returnUrl}}&invoice=%7B%22merchantEmail%22%3A%22{{merchantEmails}}%22,%22payerEmail%22%3A%22{{payerEmails}}%22,%22itemList%22%3A%7B%22item%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22{{name}}%22,%22description%22%3A%22{{description}}%22,%22quantity%22%3A%221.0%22,%22unitPrice%22%3A%22{{price}}%22,%22taxName%22%3A%22Tax%22,%22taxRate%22%3A%220.0%22%7D%5D%7D,%22currencyCode%22%3A%22{{currency}}%22,%22paymentTerms%22%3A%22DueOnReceipt%22,%22discountPercent%22%3A%220.0%22%7D"

url = url.replace("{{merchantEmails}}", "merchantEmails@merchantEmails.com");
          url = url.replace("{{payerEmails}}", "test@tesma.com");
         url = url.replace("{{price}}", "1");
         url = url.replace("{{name}}", Title);
         url = url.replace("{{description}}", "Title");
         url = url.replace("{{currency}}", "currencyType");
```